# Simple Hello World Node API fails to connectsimple Hello World Node API fails to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple hello world route with nodejs and express. When I run `node index.js`, I get `listening on port 3000` in the console, but when i go to `http://localhost:3000/helloworld`, nothing works. It keeps trying to connect.

I am probably missing something somewhere in the routes.

`index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const helloworld_route = require("./routes/helloworld");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "../.env.sample" });
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.json);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});


app.use("/", helloworld_route);
```

`controllers/hello.js`

```
const helloTest = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
  console.log("hello");
};


module.exports = {
  helloTest,
};
```

routes.helloworld.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const HelloWorld = require("../controllers/hello");


router.get("/helloworld", HelloWorld.helloTest);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The question is well asked, but the cause of the problem is a bit of a facepalm.  You just forgot `()` after `express.json`.  Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express.js **express.json()** Function

*The **express.json()** function is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on **body-parser**.*

**Syntax:**
express.json( [options] )

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const helloworld_route = require("./routes/helloworld");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "../.env.sample" });
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/", helloworld_route);


app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

You use your code **

> app.use(express.json());

**